# Multiple tabs on a browser that allows to use a different proxy on each tab

Tags: web-browser, proxy

I need a browser that allows me to run multiple tabs or instances,
but I need that each page is completely isolated.

So I should be able to use a different proxy on each page and separate cookie store and cache.

Answer (score 1):

Oni, Ghost Browser lets you isolate browsing Sessions in each tab. You can also assign a different proxy for each tab with new Ghost Proxy Control extension. No messing VMs or anything. Everything is right there in one browser window. More details here: https://ghostbrowser.com/blog/set-different-proxy-for-each-tab/

Comment: This answer appears to address directly and specifically the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Thinking out of the box *and back in* the best that I know of is to use [Virtual Box](https://www.virtualbox.org/) or VMWare to run multiple operating system instances, each with a browser running, possibly "full screen", in tabs.

- If you use a light Linux install as the base for each OS instance the memory consumption will not be much higher than some browsers. [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/) for example is 50MB and includes a browser and runs in 128 MB of RAM, [NanoLinux](https://sourceforge.net/projects/nanolinux/) is 14 MB and there are several other tiny distributions.
- You can even get 30 day licenced windows distributions, complete with browsers, from Microsoft for test use.
- Complete isolation of the browsers, cache, cookies, file system, etc.
- Virtual Box is Free & Cross Platorm
- VMWare has some free versions

Answer (score 0):

Somiibo is another software that does this as well. You can assign a unique session to each tab which means independent proxies, logins, cache, cookies, and everything. This [proxy browser](https://somiibo.com/platforms/proxy-browser) is free at the moment.